# Am I deviating from REST pattern, if I allow my user to change resource identifier of the resource during PUT calls?

Tags: rest, put

In my case I shall allow the user to update the resource using a code in the url (ex:apidomain/{code}) and can also change the code by passing it inside the model.

Am I deviating from REST pattern, if I allow my user to change resource identifier of the resource during PUT calls?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP `PUT` means "put the body of my request here", where the URL at which you make the request is where to put the entity. If you `PUT` a resource somewhere, you should be able to `GET` it again.

If the content of the request means that the resource will **not** be found at the URL you just `PUT` it at, you've broken one of the HTTP constraints.

I can think of a couple of options to handle this scenario which would all fit within HTTP's constraints:

1. Make it so that the URL of the resource is immutable. The "real" ID of any resource in a RESTful system is its URL. If you want to have an ID which is mutable, make it a surrogate key supported by an immutable identifier which is used to build the URL, or just make the URL the primary key.
2. Remove the ID of the entity from its representation (so there can be no confusion around identifiers) and perform a `PUT` of the resource to its new URL. The `PUT` should contain enough information to recognise the resource already exists at a previous location and to internally perform a "relocate" by changing the relevant ID.
3. `DELETE` the first resource and `PUT` the resource with its new ID in its new location. You might be able to track some history between the two internally, if required.

However you decide to perform a "relocation" of a resource, you should make it so anybody attempting to `GET` the old resource should receive a **301 Moved Permanently** response, which should include the new location of the resource.